# What is the reason why my room heater interferes with my computer monitor and how do I fix it?

Tags: power-supply, mains

I have a computer screen (Acer, not sure the model, it's powered through an external 220 to 19v PSU and connected via HDMI) and a fan heater connected to the same socket with a power string. Unfortunately, when I turn on or off the fan heater, the screen goes blank for a second. Electric and data cables are far away from each other, so it's not direct interference with the HDMI connection.

I tried various minimisation strategies, such as adding a long cable from the power strip to the heater or using a longer power strip, but the problem remained.

What is the nature of the issue, and is there an effective strategy to eliminate this problem?

Edit: please note that while I understand this question may appear off topic for the site, I am interested in going beyond the solution of the problem as a consumer. I do practice circuit design as a hobby, and I want to know the technical details of what is happening and what are mitigation strategies that the monitor may have not implemented in order to deal with such eventuality.

Comment: the heater appears to be causing a brownout on the monitor. Use a power strip with a higher current rating, or plug it into a different socket.

Comment: @Hearth it's rated at 10A/250V. The heater consumes 1000W, and I've seen the same issue occur when I turn on just the fan, which consumes 80W. I have a watt meter if it can be of use.